# I've installed example data on Nominee template but the published site shows another version of the site

Tags: templates

I'm making a website using [Nominee](https://themeforest.net/item/nominee-theme-for-candidatepolitical-leader/13913200?irgwc=1&clickid=z8NXbczB5QfiSScQoYUVyQOVUklSXGwGrR8sWQ0&iradid=275988&irpid=102006&iradtype=ONLINE_TRACKING_LINK&irmptype=mediapartner&mp_value1=&utm_campaign=af_impact_radius_102006&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=impact_radius) template from themeforest.

I've downloaded all the content from the demo website. Actually ended up doing it twice in two different ways, using the import functionality and then downloaded data example on the template. So my menu content is doubled, but that's another story.

While editing I see the content of the demo. However when I go to https://www.mdmdiaspora.com[https version] or http://www.mdmdiaspora.com [htpp versions] of the site I see completely different content, with none of the example data.

How can I actually publish the content I see, meaning my altered demo data ?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. The problem you describe, http and https showing different sites, sounds like a hosting issue. I would recommend you to contact your website hosting provider support to get that sorted out. And as you're using a 3rd party theme, the one you've purchased from themeforest, you should contact the theme author should you have any questions about how to setup and use the theme as 3rd party themes are considered off-topic here on WPSE.

Comment: Thank you for help Antii. Following your instructions I got my items sorted.